# Sales force Community Sign-Up using Google,Facebook & Twitter

Tags: community, salesforce1-app

Can we sign-up to salesforce community using social accounts like Google,Facebook & Twitter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **Yes**. What you need here is to set up an Auth Provider to be able to use a Social Sign-On. You should start looking for more details on Auth Provider and Social Sign-On topics. Below are some good place to get started on these topics:

- [Auth Provider](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_authentication_providers.htm&type=5)
- S[et Up Social Sign-On Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/identity_external/units/identity_external_social)